# How to know the state of the request in an array of deferred objects in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-deferred

I am developing a web application that requests information from wikipedia api.

I am able to make the requests and wait for all of them to finish inside this block of code:

```
$.when.apply(null, requestsArray).done(function () {
```

where requestsArray is my array of requests performed.

ALthough some requests are not successful, some have errors because not all i am searching for exists in wikipedia. Although i want to be able to distinguish  the ones that succeeded from the ones that didnt.

Here is an example of the objects inside the array:

```
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
**Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
    parse: Object
    warnings: Object
    __proto__: Object

Object {servedby: "mw1208", error: Object}
    error: Object
    code: "missingtitle"
    info: "The page you specified doesn't exist"
    __proto__: Object
    servedby: "mw1208"
    __proto__: Object**
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
Object {servedby: "mw1137", error: Object}
Object {servedby: "mw1204", error: Object}
Object {warnings: Object, parse: Object}
```

So in this case the requests that weren't successfuly server are the ones that have the code = missingtitle. but the other dont have any code. so how can i distinguish from both of them like in a if statement?

Comment: So what is the problem really? You have all the responses information in the `done` callback.